# Clunk in back end

Tags: toyota, transmission, suspension, rav4

I'm hearing a clunk and bang from the back of my car. The symptoms:

- 2010 RAV4, 6 cyl, AWD, 75kmiles.
- Clunk from rear sometimes when rounding sharp corners at low speed.
- Clunk from rear sometimes when shifting from reverse to drive.

I'm suspecting the rear suspension, or possibly the transmission/drive-train. Anyone have any thoughts.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Check all the rear suspension joints...

Comment: Do you hear a whirring sound sometimes when accelerating? _Could) be a worn differential. (Although I'd also vote for the rear suspension as being more likely.)

Comment: SolarMike

Thanks, will do.

the_storyteller

No, I hear no such whining, but can't say I have been paying attention closely. I will listen closely. Thanks!